# Every spark pods scheduled on a single minikube node

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, minikube

Following [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-spark-on-kubernetes/) but instead setting minikube replicas to 3

```
minikube start --nodes 3 --memory 8192 --cpus 4 # enough resources for spark

$ kubectl get nodes
NAME           STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
minikube       Ready    control-plane,master   68m   v1.22.3
minikube-m02   Ready    <none>                 68m   v1.22.3
minikube-m03   Ready    <none>                 67m   v1.22.3
```

When I apply the following deployments, everything gets scheduled on a single node, even though other nodes have enough resources.

```
$ kubectl get pods -owide
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
spark-master-9d67dd4b7-tps82    1/1     Running   0          48m   10.244.2.2    minikube-m03   <none>           <none>
spark-worker-766ccb5887-64bzk   1/1     Running   0          13s   10.244.2.17   minikube-m03   <none>           <none>
spark-worker-766ccb5887-6gvfv   1/1     Running   0          13s   10.244.2.18   minikube-m03   <none>           <none>
```

This is my deployment for workers:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: spark-worker
spec:
  replicas: 15
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: spark-worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: spark-worker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spark-worker
          image: mjhea0/spark-hadoop:3.2.0
          command: ["/spark-worker"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
```

and master:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: spark-master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: spark-master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: spark-master
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spark-master
          image: mjhea0/spark-hadoop:3.2.0
          command: ["/spark-master"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7077
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
```

Any reason why everything sits on a single node?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Had to increase the replicas to 150 for the scheduler to finally consider other nodes.